# django-cms-search not displaying any results

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-cms, whoosh

Hey I have been plugging away trying to get haystack working with whoosh to implement a search backend for a django cms project i have been working on.  After figuring out some really weird permissions errors i can almost taste sucess.

I now have haystack creating the indexes correctly and it will even display results for a custom app i have created an index for however i cannot get it to display any results for the cms page stuff.  There are results being returned as im not getting the "No Results" message but nothing is being printed out in the results.html template.

bearing in mind that im letting django-cms-search handle the indexing for the cms app i didnt think i would need to add anything extra to get the results to display.

So to outline what i have so far
Haystack installed with a Whoosh backend

my `setting.py` setting are

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'lactoseintolerant.lactose_search.search_sites'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'whoosh'
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = '/home/mike/sites/lactosetoloerant/lactoseintolerant/whoosh'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 50
```

my `search_sites.ph` file looks like

```
import haystack
from cms.models import monkeypatch_reverse
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool

monkeypatch_reverse()    
haystack.autodiscover()
```

i have a custom index for my Topics Model that looks like so (This is working and resturning Reuslts)

```
from topics.models import Topic 
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site


class TopicIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def index_queryset(self):
        """
        This is used when the entire index for model is updated, and should only include
        public entries
        """
        return Topic.objects.filter(active=True)



site.register(Topic, TopicIndex)
```

My `results.html` template look like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cache cms_tags menu_tags %}
{% block base_content %}

    <div id="panel-left">
        {% block nav %}
            <ul id="nav-left">
                {% show_menu 1 100 100 100 %}
            </ul> <!-- #nav-left -->
        {% endblock %}

        {% block panel_left %}

        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% block panel_right %}

        <div id="panel-main">           
            {% ifequal q '' %}
                <h1 id="page-head-2">Search Results Page</h1>
                <p>Please provide search criteria or keywords</p>
                <br />
                <form action=".">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ q }}">
                        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
                    </p>
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <h1 id="page-head-2">Search Results - page {{ request.GET.page|default:1 }} of {{ paginator.num_pages }}</h1>
                <h1 id="page-head-2">Found {{ paginator.count }} for <span id="searchString">'{{ q }}'</span></h1>
                <form action=".">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ q }}">
                        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
                    </p>
                </form>

                <ul id="searchResults">
                    {% for item in current_page.object_list %}

                        <li class="searchResult">
                                <h2 class="searchTitle">{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ item.get_title }}</h2>
                                <a class="searchLink" href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.get_absolute_url }}</a>
                        </li> <!-- .searchResult -->

                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>

                {% if paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
                    <div id="pagination">
                        {% for page_range_item in paginator.page_range %}
                                {% if not request.GET.page and page_range_item == 1 or request.GET.page == page_range_item|safe %}
                                    <span class="pag-link current" href="/topics/?page={{ page_range_item }}">{{ page_range_item }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    <a class="pag-link" href="/search/?q={{ q }}&page={{ page_range_item }}">{{ page_range_item }}</a>
                                {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

            {% endifequal %}

        </div>      
     {% endblock %}


     {% endblock %}
```

Im clearly missing something obvious here any help would be grealt appreciated!!

Cheers

Comment: does `from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet;
SearchQuerySet()` return any cms pages?

Comment: Did you solve it? If so please post the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you got it almost, try to change `{{ item.get_absolute_url }}` to `{{ item.object.get_absolute_url }}` inn your `results.html` file.